# Add after Update trigger to all tables in database

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am currently adding a trigger to all tables in a database using this script:

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'CREATE TRIGGER [?_Update] ON ? FOR UPDATE AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON update ? set ModifiedOn = GETDATE() END'
```

I need to change the trigger so that it only updates the changed row so it need to look like this:

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'CREATE TRIGGER [?_Update] ON ? FOR UPDATE AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON update ? set ModifiedOn = GETDATE() 
from ? updatedTable inner join inserted i 
on i.[the tables primary key] = updatedTable.[the tables primary key]
END'
```

however I do not know how to get the [the tables primary key] value.  A Trigger created by the first script looks like:

```
update [dim].[company] set ModifiedOn = GETDATE()
```

and assuming I could get the second script to work it would create this trigger:

```
update [dim].[company] set ModifiedOn = GETDATE() 
from [Dim].[Company] updatedTable
inner join inserted i on i.CompanyKey = updatedTable.CompanyKey
```

Does anyone know how to do this, or if its not possible an alternative method of adding the required trigger to all tables in the database?

The ultimate goal is to know when a record was changed, preferably human readable or that can be converted to something human readable.  I do not know when or where the updates will come from so using sprocs for update is out.

Comment: use the inserted keyword to reference the record being changed.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: I've posted an answer that will work if all of your PKs are also IDENTITY columns. If that's not so then it starts to go unpretty very fast - you need an additional metadata query so you probably don't want to use `sp_MSforeachtable` any longer, and composite PKs will make it even uglier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** all of your primary keys are, specifically, identity columns, then you can cheat and use the `IDENTITYCOL` "column" name:

```
create table T (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,Col1 varchar(10) not null,Changed datetime null)
go

create trigger T_T
on T
after insert,update
as
    update t set Changed = GETDATE()
    from inserted i
        inner join
        T t on i.IDENTITYCOL = t.IDENTITYCOL
```

`IDENTITYCOL` is effectively an automatic alias for whatever column is an identity column in that table.

---

Actually, $identity might be preferred:

```
update t set Changed = GETDATE()
from inserted i
    inner join
    T t on i.$identity = t.$identity
```

It would appear the `IDENTITYCOL` is [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Not that I can actually find an actual documentation page for either of these.